# Prove that the density topology is stronger than Euclidean topology.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm working through Franklin Tall's [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102867878) on the Density Topology. In theorem 2.3, he defines a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that if a set $E \subseteq \phi(E)$, then $E$ is open. He uses $\phi(E)$ to denote the set of density points of $E$.

He then claims that the density topology (the topology defined above) is stronger than the usual Euclidean topology. I was able to prove that an open set in the Euclidean topology is also an open set of the density topology. But I have not been able to find a set $A$ such that $A$ is open in the density topology and not open in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$? (countable sets do not affect Lebesgue measure)

Comment: @LuizCordiero A density point is $x$ such that $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{m(E \cap [x-h,x+h])}{2h} = 1$. Is this limit 1 in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$? Is that a consequence of countable sets not affecting the measure?

Comment: Yes and yes. So the measure of $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cap[x-h,x+h]$ is...?

Comment: The measure of $(\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}) \cap [x-h, x + h]$ will be $2h$. Then the limit is 1 at each point $x \in (\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q})$. So $\phi(\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R}$, and the set satisfies the requirements for an open set in the density topology.

Thank you!